# China is 98% of the bitcoin market?

Tags: exchanges, market

I saw the following graphic listing the source as Bitcoinity claiming that the Chinese exchanges are 98% of the "global bitcoin market".

[image]

Is this true?

Comment: What statistic is that chart supposed to be measuring?  Volume, holdings, something else?

Answer (score 4):

Chinese Bitcoin exchanges don't take a fee per trade and some actually reduce the withdrawal fee if more trades were made.

Outside of China, exchanges usually take a fee on each trade. The volumes therefore are not really comparable, and I sincerely doubt that the actual economic activity is so much bigger in China.